# ¿Cómo montar un disco en la ruta de Apache?

Tags: apache, http, servidor

Acabo de crear un vps de digitalocean (40GB) y un disco SSD de 100GB para almacenar el sitio web. El disco lo monté en /var/www/html con

```
$ sudo mount -o discard,defaults /dev/disk/by-id/disco-ssd /var/www/html
```

Y el fstab con esto

```
$ sudo echo /dev/disk/by-id/disco-ssd /var/www/html ext4 defaults,nofail,discard 0 0 | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
```

Utilizando ufw abrí el puerto 80 de http y cree un archivo info.php en /var/www/html/ con lo siguiente:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Pero al abrir con mi explorador la ruta http://IP/info.php aparece un error 403

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /info.php on this server.
```

Answer (score 0):

Verifica que el usuario o grupo  de apache tenga permisos de lectura en la ruta montada.

En el fstab puedes  agregar la opción gid o uid con el ID del grupo y id del usuario de apache respectivamente. Para que al montarse pertenezca a apache o su grupo.

Además verifica que en virtualhost la carpeta. Tenga permisos en la sección Directory con la instrucción allowoverryde all.

Apache solo necesita Lear los archivos  y leer y ejecutar los directorios no es necesario algún otro permiso. Para mostrar las página a menos que deseas cargar archivos o crear archivos con php deberás asignar permisos de escritura para el usuario apache o su grupo.